# RecyclerView- I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration, Firebase Data doesnt display

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to pull data from Firebase to display as live chat messenger on my Android Studio project, can push the data to firebase but it wont display in the recycler view. Any help would be great thanks!

This what the run displays when on the chat section:
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1678
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 19308639
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=22KB, data=28KB
After code cache collection, code=22KB, data=28KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 19308800
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb597e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9ee71770)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb597e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9ee71770)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb597e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9ee71770)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

````
``` package com.amazonaws.ivs.player.scrollablefeed.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import com.amazonaws.ivs.player.scrollablefeed.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.Objects;


public class LiveChat extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatViewHolder> adapter;
    RelativeLayout activity_live_chat;
    AppCompatEditText input_msg;
    ImageView submit_btn;
    RecyclerView message_list;
    Query query;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> options;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        displayChatMessage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_chat);



        activity_live_chat = findViewById(R.id.activity_chat);
        message_list = findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
        message_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        message_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
       options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                       // .setLayout(R.layout.chat_list_item)
                        .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                        .build();

        input_msg = findViewById(R.id.input);
        submit_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input_msg.getText().toString(),
                        Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getEmail()));
                input_msg.setText("");
                input_msg.requestFocus();

            }
        });

        displayChatMessage();


    }

    private void displayChatMessage() {

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatMessage model) {
                holder.textMessage.setText(model.getTextMessage());
                holder.userOfMessage.setText(model.getUserMessage());
                holder.messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.chat_list_item, parent, false);

                return new ChatViewHolder(itemView);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return 0;
            }
        };

        message_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    public static class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textMessage, userOfMessage,messageTime;


        public ChatViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            userOfMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        }
    }
}  ```
````

````
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/activity_chat"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="16dp"
       android:paddingLeft="16dp"
       android:paddingRight="16dp"
       android:paddingTop="16dp"
       tools:context=".activities.LiveChat"
       android:background="@drawable/bg_login">
   
   
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
           android:padding="4dp"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_send_msg"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp" />
   
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/input_msg"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_submit"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="Message..."
               android:id="@+id/input"/>
       </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   
       
   
       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_above="@+id/input_msg"
           android:dividerHeight="16dp"
           android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
           android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:stackFromBottom="true"
           android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
   
   
   
   
   </RelativeLayout> ```
````

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The method displayChatMessage should display the data from Firebase so you can view them all as a chat log, however the RecyclerView is blank when it runs. There is no errors at all which is way im confused as to where exactly its went wrong! just this message in the Run I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration Thanks let me know if you need to see anything else